# What is the Linux C library equivalent of .Net `CharUnicodeInfo` Class

Tags: linux, unicode, glibc

On Windows, you can obtain information about a Unicode character with class

[CharUnicodeInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo?view=net-5.0)

from the Dot-Net 5 API.

So for example, you can obtain the information that `0x0BEF`, ["TAMIL DIGIT NINE"](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0BEF), belongs to character class `DecimalDigitNumber` via method [CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.getunicodecategory?view=net-5.0)

(Although that method gives `DecimalDigitNumber` the correct category name is apparently [`Decimal_Number`](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B:General_Category=Decimal_Number:%5D) ... confusing)

If I am on Linux and have gcc, what do I call there?

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/contrib/unicode/from_glibc/unicode_utils.py and https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/gen-uni-tables.c might helps, though I have no idea how to actually use them

Comment: GNU `libc` basically inherits this from the ICU. Perhaps use that directly.